# Como eu pego o valor de um checkbox para passar por parametro

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

Gostaria de saber como eu pego o status de uma checkbox se ela esta ativada ou não para passar por parâmetro para o controller

[image: Estou fazendo isto, mais toda hora vem "True"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a ideia é checar se o *check* está marcado, a consulta deve ser feita como abaixo:

```
var checkado = $("#chkAguardandoEnvio").prop("checked");
```

Caso seja saber se o *check* está habilitado para marcação, use este outro:

```
var habilitado = $("#chkAguardandoEnvio").attr("disabled") != undefined;
```